# How to display datas into a tableview Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to display into 3 labels "Home", "Info", "Log Out" and for each one a image.
This is for a sidebar menu. So, I use case, because for each case, I do an action.

```
enum SideMenuItem: String, CaseIterable{
    case home
    case info
    case logout
 
}

class MenuController: UITableViewController {


    private let menuItems: [SideMenuItem]
```

This is my .xib cell.
[image]

And this is my code for the table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].rawValue

        return cell
    }
```

Into the labels I want to display : "Home", "info", "Log Out", and into the imageView, I have 3 items in my assets, but This is what i am getting: [image]

Comment: That's because you are setting the menuItems value to textLabel.text.

Answer (score 0):

For your tableview cell i.e. `SideMenuCell.swift`, create an IBOutlet for label.

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
```

And in your `cellForRowAt`  set the text for label as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuCell
        cell.labelName.text = menuItems[indexPath.row].rawValue

        return cell
    }
```